# Should string variables local to a function generally have thread local (rather than automatic) storage class?

Tags: c++

In this code, consider the logically equivalent functions `g1` and `g2`:

```
#include <string>

void f(std::string &);

void g1()
{
    std::string s;
    f(s);
}

void g2()
{
    thread_local std::string s;
    s.clear();
    f(s);
}
```

The corresponding assembler code (from x86-64 clang 17.0.1) is (from https://godbolt.org/z/ccnboo4nY ):

```
g1():                                 # @g1()
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     r14, [rsp + 24]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], r14
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], 0
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 24], 0
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        call    f(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)@PLT
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        cmp     rdi, r14
        je      .LBB0_3
        call    operator delete(void*)@PLT
.LBB0_3:
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        ret
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        cmp     rdi, r14
        je      .LBB0_6
        call    operator delete(void*)@PLT
.LBB0_6:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [base object destructor]: # @std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [base object destructor]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rdi]
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jne     operator delete(void*)@PLT                      # TAILCALL
        ret
g2():                                 # @g2()
        push    rax
        cmp     byte ptr fs:[guard variable for g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF], 0
        je      .LBB2_1
.LBB2_2:
        mov     rax, qword ptr fs:[0]
        lea     rdi, [rax + g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF]
        mov     qword ptr fs:[g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF+8], 0
        mov     rax, qword ptr fs:[g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF]
        mov     byte ptr [rax], 0  # std::string::clear()
        pop     rax
        jmp     f(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)@PLT # TAILCALL
.LBB2_1:
        mov     rax, qword ptr fs:[0]
        lea     rcx, [rax + g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF+16]
        mov     qword ptr fs:[g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF], rcx
        lea     rsi, [rax + g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF]
        mov     qword ptr fs:[g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF+8], 0
        mov     byte ptr fs:[g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF+16], 0
        lea     rdi, [rip + std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [base object destructor]]
        lea     rdx, [rip + __dso_handle]
        call    __cxa_thread_atexit@PLT
        mov     byte ptr fs:[guard variable for g2()::s[abi:cxx11]@TPOFF], 1
        jmp     .LBB2_2
g2()::s[abi:cxx11]:
        .zero   32

guard variable for g2()::s[abi:cxx11]:
        .byte   0                               # 0x0

DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0:
        .quad   __gxx_personality_v0
```

(x86-64 gcc 13.2 produces similar assembler code.)  Note that calling `std::string::clear` doesn't release any allocated storage for the string's value.  (That is, the string instance's capacity is not changed.)  It seems likely that there would be fewer dynamic storage allocations and deallocations associated with the string variable, over the lifetime of each thread.  The drawback being, that the storage would not be available for other purposes.  This drawback might be offset by less heap fragmentation.  Thread local storage also seems to reduce exception handling object code.

Comment: Unless `f` does something with the string, maybe the end result is the same anyway.

Comment: For something like this, maybe this makes sense, but the optimizing compiler can pull some really neat tricks with `s` when it knows it's short lived.

Comment: They're not logically equivalent.  One uses thread-local storage (which has implicit `static` for a block scope variable).

Comment: @tadman you may very well be right.  Maybe an expert will answer "no", and support the answer with more realistic code.

Comment: @user4581301 it would seem plausible, given how common strings are, that compilers would support optimizations of them as though std::string was an intrinsic type.  But, so far, I've always been disappointed looking for them.  For example:  https://godbolt.org/z/MnbMnWqqG .  You would think, in a short function like this, the optimizer could change heap to stack allocation.  (Although that could be bad for a bare-bones embedded target.)

Comment: To answer the question in your title, no, they shouldn’t.

Comment: @WaltK Agree with you on that one. There are a lot of places where I'd have like to see a dynamic allocation just... go away because it's not necessary.

Comment: @Eljay not sure what you mean, that seems like a matter of implementation, not logic.  My example code is bad in every way other than brevity.  Here's an alternative example:  https://godbolt.org/z/b6acETYnM .  Much harder to wade through.  But fewer heap operations still seems likely.  I would think "replace" and "mutate" would avoid reallocation if the capacity was already adequate.

Comment: Unrelated: why is the compiler generating so much output for functions which are not being called from anywhere?

Comment: @kiner_shah: it is only one TU (translation unit), another one might call those functions. they cannot be removed.

Comment: @Jarod42, like via `extern` or including this file somewhere?